# Unable to install vss6 in wine1.6 on ubuntu 14.04 64bit

Tags: 14.04, wine

after i click next on first screen it's always shows up "program error"

please help

for image

http://imageshack.com/a/img843/8290/8v81.png

and this error.

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000000 in 32-bit code (0x0040e449).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:0040e449 ESP:0033b8d8 EBP:00000000 EFLAGS:00010216(  R- --  I   -A-P- )
 EAX:7bc4b629 EBX:ffffff31 ECX:0033c00c EDX:00000000
 ESI:00000000 EDI:0000004e
Stack dump:
0x0033b8d8:  0000004e 0033c00c ffffff31 0040dce4
0x0033b8e8:  0041f278 00010082 0040ec47 0033cfd0
0x0033b8f8:  00010082 0033c7f8 7ea46000 00000001
0x0033b908:  0033b928 00220024 0033c472 0033b9a8
0x0033b918:  0033b948 f75938bb 4d430003 00000000
0x0033b928:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
000c: sel=0067 base=00000000 limit=00000000 32-bit r-x
Backtrace:
=>0 0x0040e449 in setup (+0xe449) (0x00000000)
0x0040e449: cmpb    $0x0,0x0(%esi)
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (67 modules)
PE    400000-  486000   Export          setup
ELF 7ac00000-7ac5f000   Deferred        riched20<elf>
  \-PE  7ac10000-7ac5f000   \               riched20
ELF 7b800000-7ba5b000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7ba5b000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcdb000   Deferred        ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcdb000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7dccc000-7de02000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7dce0000-7de02000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7de02000-7de83000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7de10000-7de83000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7de83000-7dfbf000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7dea0000-7dfbf000   \               ole32
ELF 7e05a000-7e07f000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e060000-7e07f000   \               imm32
ELF 7e07f000-7e0b6000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7e090000-7e0b6000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7e0b6000-7e0bc000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7e0bc000-7e0c7000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7e0c7000-7e0d8000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7e0d8000-7e0dc000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7e0dc000-7e0e7000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7e0e7000-7e0f2000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7e0f2000-7e0f8000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7e0f8000-7e0fc000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7e0fc000-7e103000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7e103000-7e107000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7e107000-7e129000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7e129000-7e25d000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7e25d000-7e270000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7e274000-7e288000   Deferred        riched32<elf>
  \-PE  7e280000-7e288000   \               riched32
ELF 7e28a000-7e31c000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7e290000-7e31c000   \               winex11
ELF 7e391000-7e3ba000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7e3ba000-7e3f5000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7e3f5000-7e41d000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7e41d000-7e437000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7e437000-7e4d6000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7e4f0000-7e518000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7e500000-7e518000   \               mpr
ELF 7e518000-7e592000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e530000-7e592000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e592000-7e7c5000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e5a0000-7e7c5000   \               shell32
ELF 7e7c5000-7e837000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e7d0000-7e837000   \               advapi32
ELF 7e837000-7e954000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e840000-7e954000   \               gdi32
ELF 7e954000-7eaae000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e970000-7eaae000   \               user32
ELF 7eaae000-7ebb5000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7eac0000-7ebb5000   \               comctl32
ELF 7ebb5000-7ebc2000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ebc2000-7ebce000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ebce000-7ebe7000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ebe7000-7ebf0000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF 7efa0000-7efe6000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe6000-7f000000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               version
ELF f739e000-f754d000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f754d000-f7552000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f7553000-f756f000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f7589000-f773e000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7740000-f7762000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f7762000-f7763000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    00000027    0
    00000020    0
    0000001a    0
    00000018    0
    00000016    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001f    0
    0000001b    0
    00000019    0
    00000013    0
00000014 explorer.exe
    0000001e    0
    00000015    0
0000001c plugplay.exe
    00000023    0
    00000022    0
    0000001d    0
00000024 (D) C:\SourceSafe\VSS60C\SETUP.EXE
    00000025    0 <==
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.6.2
    Platform: i386
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 3.13.0-24-generic
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the program you are using does not work with Wine 1.6. It might help if you use Wine 1.7 development version instead of 1.6. Although 1.7 is slightly unstable, I recommend using it anyway because it is compatible with many more programs. To install it, just make sure you are using the Wine PPA (which you probably are if you have 1.6) and remove the `wine1.6` package and install the `wine1.7` package.

Comment: but i searched for supported program https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=308 Microsoft Visual Sourcesafe 6 supported since wine version 1.4.1

Comment: i try `wine1.7` also error.